# npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fcore failed, reason:

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json, econnreset

Getting error while installing npm
[root@mbiazdevops UAT]# npm install --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fcore failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/node-v16.15.1-linux-x64/npm-cache/_logs/2023-04-24T06_45_21_833Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to go to https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fcore in a browser? The error means that the network connection to the registry failed, which is most likely a network problem.

Comment: I am able to connect to the registry in the browser and even through terminal it returns Head 200 ok